# CMake error : catkin_make :::Running command Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/ws/build"

Tags: cmake

I'm creating ros workspace by create_pkg. but I can't build by next error.
Do you know how to solve the problem?
​
I try next step in empty folder
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
​$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src

$ catkin_init_workspace
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/

$ catkin_make

but this test raise error too.

​

Running command: "cmake /ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "ws/build"

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0

-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0

-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc

-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done

-- Detecting C compile features

-- Detecting C compile features - done

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

-- Detecting CXX compile features

-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: ws/devel

-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: m_ws/devel;/opt/ros/melodic

-- This workspace overlays: /m_ws/devel;/opt/ros/melodic

-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.17", minimum required is "2")

-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2

-- Using Debian Python package layout

-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy

-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON

-- Call enable_testing()

-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/a307/ws/build/test_results

-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built

-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built

-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.17")

-- Looking for pthread.h

-- Looking for pthread.h - found

-- Looking for pthread_create

-- Looking for pthread_create - not found

-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads

-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found

-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread

-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found

-- Found Threads: TRUE

-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7

-- catkin 0.7.29

-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on

-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on

-- Configuring done

-- Generating done

-- Build files have been written to: /ws/build

Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/ws/build"

Comment: Please, show the complete **error message**. Currently you show only output of configuration process, and it is successful. Note: for format code and logs you may select the text and press `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button on toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

First your catkin_ws folder. (you should be in home folder now)

```
rm -rf catkin_ws
```

Then

```
mkdir -p catkin_ws/src && cd catkin_ws/src
```

Create your package using

```
catkin_create_pkg mypkg rospy roscpp std_msgs
cd .. 
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
catkin_make
```

Now, you should be able to do `catkin_make`

after this you should setup your workspace in .bashrc

```
echo 'source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash' >> ~/.bashrc
```

you are good to go now... run `roscore`